# File descriptor of getch()

Tags: c, ncurses, curses, libev

I want to use libev to listen for keyboard (keystrokes) events in the terminal. My idea is to use (n)curses getch() and set notimeout() (to be nonblocking) to tell getch() not to wait for next keypress.

Is there a file descriptor that getch uses I can watch?

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: [`STDIN_FILENO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29)?

Comment: Hmmm I thought stdin was bypassed, Will try it =)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you where correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `initscr()`, the file descriptor you ask for is `fileno(stdin)`, since the initscr subroutine is equivalent to:

```
newterm(getenv("TERM"), stdout, stdin); return stdscr;
```

If you use `newterm(type, outfile, infile)`, the file descriptor is `fileno(infile)`.

Answer (score 2):

Curses, and all the terminal functions are actually communicating with the actual terminal through the normal standard input and output file descriptors.

What it does is changing flags using special `ioctl` calls or sending special control codes directly that are parsed by the terminal program.

This means that the `getch` function just reads its input from the standard input, which if you want a file descriptor is `STDIN_FILENO` (from the `<unistd.h>` header file).

Answer (score 0):

This is a getch like function. I'm on Windows now so can't retest it. If you want 
it to just listen and not display the chars change like this : `newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);`

```
int getch(void)
{
  struct termios oldt, newt;
  int ch;
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
  newt = oldt;
  newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
  ch = getchar();
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
  return ch;
}
```