# NCurses stdin redirection

Tags: c, ncurses

I don't understand why the getch() function returns ERR all the time if I have an application
set up in this manner (stripped to the bones):

```
static char data[DATA_SIZE]; // Very big - covers all input for sure

int main(int argn, char ** argv)
{

  // Slurp the file in
  int length = read(0, &data[0], DATA_SIZE);
  if (length == 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Nothing to read\n");
    return 0;
  }

  initscr();
  cbreak();
  refresh();
  WINDOW * woutput = newwin(LINES - 1, COLS, 0, 0);
  WINDOW * winput  = newwin(1, COLS, LINES - 1, 0);
  wattron(winput, A_REVERSE);
  keypad(winput, TRUE);

   //print the data buffer into a window

  int c;
  while ((c = wgetch(winput)) != 'q')
  {
  }
}
```

I run the application in this manner:

```
./application < path/to/file
```

But the result of wgetch is always `'ERR'`.

Comment: Ah, I see .It returns -1 - why isn't it getting my tty's input  after the file ? Is there a way to get it to work that way ?

Comment: Where is the tty's output going to ? Discarded ? Anyway, it makes sense - I don't know  why I thought it would come thereafter the file end. my bad

Comment: I think you may be right - if you set that to be an aswer I could mark  it with the green flag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File descriptor of getch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734387/file-descriptor-of-getch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have read `stdin` up to the end of file, `wgetch` will immediately receive an end of file when it attempts to read. But in any case, you don't want ncurses to use the redirected `stdin`; you want it to use the terminal.

One way of doing this is to simply reopen `stdin` as the terminal before calling `initscr`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argn, char ** argv)
{
  // Just discard all of stdin for a minimal example
  while (fgetc(stdin) != EOF) { }

  // See note
  if (!freopen("/dev/tty", "r", stdin)) {
    perror("/dev/tty");
    exit(1);
  }
  initscr();

  cbreak();
  refresh();
  WINDOW * woutput = newwin(LINES - 1, COLS, 0, 0);
  WINDOW * winput  = newwin(1, COLS, LINES - 1, 0);
  wattron(winput, A_REVERSE);
  keypad(winput, TRUE);

  // Echo input into full screen
  int c;
  while ((c = wgetch(winput)) != 'q') { wechochar(woutput, c); }
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

If you find `freopen` hard to follow, you could replace it and the following call to `initscr` with

```
FILE* tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");
if (!tty) { perror("/dev/tty"); exit(1); }
if (!newterm(NULL, stdout, tty) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Unable to initialise ncurses");
  exit(1);
}
```

#### Note:

In the above code, I just used `/dev/tty` as the name of the console, which will probably work in any moderately Posix compliant system. However, Posix also provides an interface which lets you discover the pathname for the current "controlling terminal", and importantly lets you know if there isn't one for your process. See [man ctermid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctermid.3p.html) for details and an example of use.

Comment: I actually used dup2(ttyfd, 0)

Comment: @pietro: Presumably after having done something like `ttyfd = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");`. That will work, too, but it doesn't reset the eof or error flags associated with `stdin`, which may cause problems. You should call `clearerr(stdin)` as well. Or just use `freopen` :-)

Comment: `newterm` is the preferred call rather than making assumptions about `initscr`

Comment: @ThomasDickey: I was going to suggest that but reopening stdin seemed simpler. Are you saying that we cannot assume that `initscr` will use `stdin`?

Comment: Both are documented, but `newterm`'s easier to follow.